# Stuck in Ubuntu booting?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-gnome

I have a problem after I did some change to the /usr/share/gnome-shell dir, I replaced it with a new theme gnome-shell dir. After which I restarted the system then came to this screen and can’t do anything from here. I have added the snapshot to the screen where I got stuck. I am using Ubuntu 18.
i used a gnome-shell theme called "Flex Remix". I thought of following the instruction given below but instead of replacing the .gresource file i replaced the whole gnome-shell dir.
how can i recover from this?

---

### [Login theme installation (As root) Replace the file gnome-shell-theme.gresource from /usr/share/gnome-shell with the provided one for each variant. This will also replace gnome-shell's default theme.](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1013030/)

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and include the changes you made, the theme you replaced it with, the complete error message from the screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get to recovery mode...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt,type `sudo mount -o rw,remount /` # to remount the disk r/w
- now go and undo the changes that you made

**Update #1:**

The user restored the previously deleted `/usr/share/gnome-shell` directory, using a copy from the Ubuntu Live USB. User should check that the directory/file ownership is correct on the restored directory.

Comment: i followed your instructions. Then i removed the gnome-shell dir, also purged the whole gnome-shell-extension. Still stuck in the same place.

Comment: @dave127 time to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: is there a way that i can restore either by usb boot or something? i have some important files.

Comment: @dave_17 yes. Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in "Try Ubuntu" mode. Connect an external USB disk drive. Copy off the files.

Comment: i will add a comment as soon as i can get a result.

Comment: omg this actually worked. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

- Booted a Ubuntu Live USB. (ubuntu 18.0.4)
- Copied the 'gnome-shell' dir from the Live ubuntu using a external HDD (NTFS drive to keep the dir's integrity) by manually mounting them, you can find help from [here](https://vitux.com/how-to-manually-mount-unmount-a-usb-device-on-ubuntu/).
- Reboot the ubuntu system in Recovery Mode and get root access.
- Find the HDD by following the help above.
- Mount the HDD.
- Copy the dir from HDD to your /usr/share dir.
- Reboot.

Comment: i answered it myself the steps i have taken to solve this problem.

Comment: @dave_17 you may wish to check that the dir/file ownership is correct on the restored directory.

Comment: yes, copied the dir in a NTFS drive to keep the dir's integrity.